# Deploy app to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I am a beginner app developer.  I have completed an app, and I have been working on it for more than a year, and finally is ready to be uploaded. I would like to upload the app as an individual, and it is also supposed to be a paid app. 
I am from Nepal, where international payment is a big issue. I can pay for the developer account. However, I am confused about the tax and other bindings. Since I am an individual, how can I set up for the tax information as I doubt it that my bank account from Nepal will not work for this? Could someone suggest me on, how to settle this, so that I could upload my app as soon as possible?

Thank you!

Comment: The most useful you can do is to contact Apple directly by using this link : https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/select

Comment: Old but gold. Link:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/120-how-to-submit-an-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation gives an in depth description on how to submit. Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: Yeah, i had gone through it. But there was nothing for the countries that would not be able to make online transaction. I have emailed the support. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: I was trying to make payment from one of my friend's credit card, but looks like I have to match the apple id and the cardholder id. Do I have to use his Appleid?

Comment: Finally, my developer account is UP. I used my friend's card. Now, for the taxation system, they are telling me that I have to use my own details. My Nepalese bank details would not work at all, and I wanted to connect directly through my friend's id.

Comment: can you set this as the answer:D